# Get the last inserted serial value from Ifxpy. Is there a documentation/ Code example for IfxPy.get_last_serial_value?

Tags: python, informix

I'm trying to get the last inserted serial value of an insert query from Python3 - Informix.
Official github https://github.com/OpenInformix/IfxPy
Last line says there is a method "IfxPy.get_last_serial_value".
But there are no details about that (Like documentation or Code sample)

May i get a code sample or documentation?

I did try to get "dbinfo('sqlca.sqlerrd1')" from systables.

```
        max_po_id_tuple = IfxPy.fetch_tuple(header_stmt)
        if max_po_id_tuple != False:
            print('inserted po_id ::' + str(max_po_id_tuple[0]))
```

("'bool' object is not subscriptable",)
'bool' object is not subscriptable

Comment: ```po_id_select_sql = "SELECT dbinfo('sqlca.sqlerrd1') AS id FROM systables WHERE tabname='mytable'"; header_stmt = IfxPy.exec_immediate(conn, po_id_select_sql)
        max_po_id_tuple = IfxPy.fetch_tuple(header_stmt)
        if max_po_id_tuple != False:
            print('inserted po_id ::' + str(max_po_id_tuple[0]))```

Answer (score 0):

Alright guys, i solved it like this

```
stmt = IfxPy.prepare(conn, "select dbinfo('sqlca.sqlerrd1') from dummy")
        IfxPy.execute(stmt)
        row = IfxPy.fetch_tuple(stmt)
        inserted_val = row[0]
        print(inserted_val)
```

Where inserted_val is my last inserted 'serial' id